# why is my api request going to web route instead of api route? Laravel 5.5.33

Tags: php, vuejs2, axios, laravel-5.5

Am trying to set up a SPA with Vuejs and Laravel at the backend Which made to configure the web route to accept all path and return the home page but

all my ajax request with axios

```
signin(context, data) {
    axios.post(`${this.base_url}/api/signin`,data)
    .then(response => {
        context.error = false
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', response.data.meta.token)
        this.user.authenticated = true
        this.user.profile = response.data.data
        router.push({
            path: '/'
        })
    }).catch(errors => {
        console.dir(errors.response.data)
        context.errors = errors.data
        context.error = true
    })
},
```

are going to laravel web route

```
<?php Route::any('{all}', function () {return view('index'); })->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

instead of api route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api']], function () {
Route::post('/api/register', [
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@register',
]);

Route::post('/api/signin', [
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@signin',
]);

Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt'], function () {
    Route::get('/user', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@index',
    ]);
});
```

});

Please can anyone explain to me why this happening?

Comment: Did you try commenting out the web-route and see if the request is then redirected to the api-route? My guess is that the web-route is catching all requests since you used the wildcard for all.

Comment: Yes I did but it was throwing exceptions route not defined 
What later did is to move all my route to web and the the web guard from session to api

Comment: And now all your routes are in web?

Comment: yes they're it seems like the JWT is preventing it

Comment: But is the {all}-route first in the routes-file? If so you might want to put it at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove api routes from routes/web.php file and place it in routes/api.php file

```
Route::post('/api/register', [
     'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@register',
]);

Route::post('/api/signin', [
     'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@signin',
]);

Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt'], function () {
      Route::get('/user', [
          'uses' => 'UserController@index',
      ]);
});
```

Your web.php should only contain

```
Route::any('{all}', function () {return view('index'); })->where(['all' => '.*']);
```